# Issues in reading text file into list view c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read a text file line by line and using delimiter , split the text and insert it into three columns in list view . Every time i click on a button , the read function has to be implemented . But I am getting repeated values when i click on the button twice. How do i fix that ? I am a beginner in c#

**Text in file**

abc*def*ghi

jkl*mno*pqr

**Output in List View**

abc|def|ghi

jkl|mno|pqr

abc|def|ghi

jkl|mno|pqr

```
  public void read(string destinination)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        StreamReader sw = File.OpenText(destinination);
        string s = "";

        try
        {
            while ((s = sw.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = s.Split('*');
                ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(words[0].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(words[1].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(words[2].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(lv);
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        sw.Close();


    }
```

Comment: Maybe called `listView1.Items.Clear();` before the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

When you twice click on your button, Following line is repeated twice:

```
 listView1.Items.Add(lv);
```

Either you need to recreate the object listView1 at the start of your function or you need to clear it at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Simply clear the ListView before adding items to it, so that when you click on the button next time, the already added items are cleared.

```
public void read(string destinination)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    StreamReader sw = File.OpenText(destinination);
    string s = "";
    ListView1.Item.Clear();
    try
    {
        while ((s = sw.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = s.Split('*');
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(words[0].ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(words[1].ToString());
            lv.SubItems.Add(words[2].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    sw.Close();


}
```